# Can't get jquery script to work

Tags: wp-enqueue-script

I am having problems using jquery on my Wordpress site.  I’m not sure if I’m including it properly.
I have added this to functions.php :

```
function mytheme_custom_scripts(){

wp_enqueue_script( 'my-test-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/my-jquery-script.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true );

}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mytheme_custom_scripts' );
```

Then added a new file to my .js folder with this jquery code on it to test if it is working:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, a').css('color','pink');
});
```

I also tried in No Conflict  mode:

```
jquery(document).ready(function(){
  jquery('h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, a').css('color','pink');
});
```

OR

```
jquery(document).ready(function(){
  $('h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, a').css('color','pink');
});
```

Nothing happens.

I can see it my footer in html form using Firebug,

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.zachgervaise.com/wp-content/themes/brianstheme/js/my-jquery-script.js?ver=1.0"></script>
```

Am I missing something?
I have been stuck on this problem for a while and as I am only an amateur Wordpress website builder any advice explained as simply and clearly as is possible would be really, really appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is becuase you didn't enqueue jquery, replce your `mytheme_custom_scripts()` function with below code.

```
function mytheme_custom_scripts(){

    // include jquery
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');

    wp_enqueue_script( 'my-test-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/my-jquery-script.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true );

}
```

and jQuery code like this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $('h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, a').css('color','pink');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your speedy response Govind Kumar. I made the relevant code changes as you suggested but there is still nothing happening.

Comment: change `jquery` to `jQuery` inside your http://www.zachgervaise.com/wp-content/themes/brianstheme/js/my-jquery-script.js file

Comment: I copied and pasted your above code and it still doesn't do anything?

Comment: i think it's working now http://www.zachgervaise.com/ @briang

Comment: YEAH! Thanks Govind Kumar. It is working now. You've made my day. That problem has been driving me insane for almost 2 weeks. i should have just asked the question straight away and saved all the trouble.

Comment: welcome, you can mark as correct answer, so that it can be helpful for someone else ;) @briang